# SP10 Edit Custom Ribbon Action Created with Designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, ribbon

If I have created a Custom Ribbon action using the Designer method, how do I then edit the action properties (i.e. button image) later?

[MSDN - Creating a Custom Action by Using SharePoint Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh500259%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_sp14_ta_AddCustomActiontoDisplay_CreatingCustomActionSharePointDesigner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is for the dummies like me who do not know how to scroll. If you scroll down on the list page you will find the `Custom Actions` section. Editing on Custom Ribbon Actions is done here...

[image: Custom Actions]